# How to divide column A grand total with Column B subtotals for different categories in Tableau that changes with the view?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I want to divide **Fee Paid $** of **Level 1 category items: (Interchange Fee, Merchant Service Fee, Scheme)** or just any one of the items in **Level 1 category (using a filter)** with just the subtotal of **Value $ of Level 1 Category: Total**. For example, **Fee$ (Interchange Fee, Merchant Services Fee, Scheme)/Value $(Total)**. Please note: the analysis shown in the table is for 1 of 1000 agencies for a particular month. I need the analysis change as per the window, as i change between agencies or months. Using a Fixed function gives a total across the entire dataset, and didn;t change with the window, doesn't work. I want the Grand Total and subtotals to change with view.
[[image: Sample table for one agency out of a 10001]

A sample data is available to download from https://community.tableau.com/s/contentdocument/0698b00000QoT4MAAV

Answer (score 1):

Could you use user level filters to change the view based on which agency you are representing in the table?

Comment: Hi Matt. I can use level filters indeed. the challange here is from Level 1 category i want to pick Interchange Fee +Marchant Service Fee+ Scheme Fee for Fee column and Totals only for Value $ column. How to do that. It is because, if I do sum(Fee)/sum(Transaction) that will be incorrect, because, the $ Value per row is incorect.  The $ Value in the Total group is correct only. On the other hand, The Fee in Totals is incorrect, so to get the Total fees I will have to Interchange Fee +Marchant Service Fee+ Scheme Fee. So I do not want a row by row division. Fixed function cannot be used as well